# Distributed transaction on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, distributed-transactions

Can someone tell me about how I can perform a distributed transaction on PostgreSQL?

I need to start transaction from a node x to node y (this node has a database).
But I don't find information on internet on how I can do it.

All I can do is a distributed query with:

```
select dblink_connect
('conn','dbname=ConsultaRemota host=192.168.3.9 
 user=remoto password=12345 port=5432');

select * from dblink('conn','select * from tablaremota') as
temp (id_remoto int, nombre_remoto text, descripcion text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dblink is no true distributed transaction, because it is possible that the remote transaction succeeds, while the local transaction fails.

To perform a distributed transaction:

1. Create a normal transaction with `BEGIN` or `START TRANSACTION` on both databases.
2. Perform work on both databases.
3. Once you are done, prepare the transaction on both databases:

   ```
   PREPARE TRANSACTION 'some_name';
   ```

   This step will perform everything that could potentially fail during `COMMIT` and persist the transaction, but it will not yet commit it.

   If that step fails somewhere, use `ROLLBACK` or `ROLLBACK PREPARED` to abort the transaction on all databases.
4. Commit the transaction on all databases:

   ```
   COMMIT PREPARED 'some_name';
   ```

   This is guaranteed to succeed.

To reliably perform a distributed transaction, you need a *transaction manager*: that is a piece of software that keeps track of all distributed transactions. This component has to persist its information, so that it can survive a crash. The job of the transaction manager is to commit or rollback any transaction that was left in an incomplete state after a crash.

This is necessary, because prepared transactions will stay around even if you restart the database, and they will hold locks and block `VACUUM` progress. Such orphaned prepared transactions can break your database.

**Never use distributed transactions without a transaction manager!**

Comment: How can I say transaction  that the databade is in another pc.

Comment: With the connect string.

Comment: That's my problem :"(, can you help me?

Comment: That is a different question. But be warned that Stackoverflow is a Q&A forum, it is not suitable for tutorials or teaching sessions.

Comment: I've seen a lot of people seeking help with any question and a lot of people help. thank you anyway :").

Comment: I am not unwilling to help, otherwise I would not answer on this forum. But you essentially say, "I don't know how to connect to a remote database, can you teach me?" Can you imagine a clear, succinct answer to such a question?